# Vim doesn't seem to register the code type

Tags: r, vim, color-scheme

I'm using VIM as my editor for R. I'm starting to have quite a few lines and the colorscheme could really come in handy. When I change it however, the background and line numbers change, but nothing in the code does.

I have `#! /usr/bin/Rscript` at the beginning of my code and the text is save as a `.r`

I also went into my `.vimrc` to add two lines to make sure that it recognized `.r` or `.R` as rscript.

I'm working on OSX.

Thanks!

Comment: Note: The colorscheme in Vim is just a mapping from parsed syntax groups to your preferred colors; what you want is a _syntax plugin_ that actually provides the parsing patterns for R.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you mean *syntax highlighting*, in which case this would be a good plugin. [Vim R Plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628).